# How do I fix the error '.has is not a function' when using JavaScript Map?

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6, hashmap, es6-class

I have the following code that attempts to set a value in a Map:

```
class Trie {
  constructor () {
    this.trie = new Map()
  }

  insert(word) {
    let current = this.trie
    for (let alpha of word) {
      if (!current.has(alpha)) current.set(alpha, [])
      current = current.get(alpha)
    }
    current.word = word
  }
}

let trie = new Trie()
trie.insert('test')
console.log(trie.trie)
```

When I attempt to run it, I get the error `.has is not a function`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're reassigning `current` to a non-Map value inside the loop, so on subsequent iterations, `current.has` will not work. Sounds like you need to change the `[]` to a `new Map` instead.

```js
class Trie {
  constructor () {
    this.trie = new Map()
  }

  insert(word) {
    let current = this.trie
    for (let alpha of word) {
      if (!current.has(alpha)) current.set(alpha, new Map())
      current = current.get(alpha)
    }
    current.word = word
  }
}

let trie = new Trie()
trie.insert('test')
console.log([...trie.trie])
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, I cant believe I missed that